# PHP - password_hash variant for older PHP version?

Tags: php

So, for a school project I'm making a website. Security is a big part of this project, so I want to at least hash my passwords before storing them. Problem is, the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` methods are only availabe starting from PHP version 5.5. The school's server is running version 5.3.3, so I can't use these methods and they refuse to update their PHP version.

Anybody know of a way I can still securely store and check my passwords?

Comment: For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Perhaps you should suggest that your school upgrade the version of PHP on their server, at least to a supported version

Comment: Agreed with @MarkBaker. 5.3 is past its [end of life](http://php.net/eol.php) and should no longer be used.

Comment: @twentylemon The link Fred has above is actually a wrapper for crypt and should be used for forward compatibility if/when the school decides to update their PHP.

Comment: @MarkBaker: I've done so already, but they don't want to for some reason.

Comment: *Hm....*, come to think of it, that link I gave for the compatibility pack, I thought would be good for 5.3.3 but states *This library requires PHP >= 5.3.7* so you will need to use crypt http://php.net/crypt

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yeah, I've noticed that too. Guess I'll have to do it with just using the `crypt()` function like @twentylemon suggested

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually it says "This library requires PHP >= 5.3.7 **OR a version that has the $2y fix backported into it**", which could be the case here. Either way, if you're using plain crypt you won't be able to use $2y, so you could just use the same library above but change the source code all occurrences of $2y to $2a and it would be just as good (if not better) than trying to write your own from scratch.

Comment: Try either one Venser, but as @Mike mentioned just above, you may  be able to get away with it. (Thanks Mike).

Comment: I think I'm just going to use the `crypt()` function, but I'll include a note when I hand in the assignment that they should really consider updating their PHP version, so that better methods can be used. Thanks for helping out @Fred-ii- and @Mike! (And sorry about the duplicate).

Comment: IIRC, the problem with the compatibility pack lay specifically in version 5.3.6 of PHP , and I think that it may work correctly with versions 5.3.0 to 5.3.5, and then with 5.3.7 upwards.... but don't quote me on that

Comment: @MarkBaker The problem exists if your version of PHP crypt doesn't have support for $2y, which was added in 3.3.7 and backported by some distros to earlier versions.